# Cocoapods : spec.prefix_header_contents does not work

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods

Here is my podspec :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "MyCBDLumberJack"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.source       = { :git => 'https://me@bitbucket.org/me/mycbdlumberjack.git', 
                    :tag =>  "#{s.version}" }
  s.source_files  = 'MyCBDLumberJack/My Lumberjack/**/*.{h,m}'
  s.public_header_files = 'MyCBDLumberJack/**/InitializationCocoaLumberjack.h'
  s.resource  = "MyCBDLumberJack/Help_MyCBDLumberJack.rtfd"
  s.ios.platform   = :ios, '5.0'
  s.osx.platform   = :osx, '10.7'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.osx.framework = 'AppKit'
  s.ios.framework = 'UIKit'
  s.prefix_header_contents = '#import "DDLog.h"'
  s.dependency 'CocoaLumberjack', '~>1.8'
end
```

But, I don't see any result for it. The `#import "DDLog.h"` does not appear in `Pods-MyCBDLumberJack-prefix.pch`.

Am I looking at the wrong place?

PS: it seems that the line is included when linting but is not included when I include the pod in a project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my mistake. The `path` to my `repo` was wrong...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I posted the question!

Comment: @Parag, please pay attention before posting comments like that... please *do* continue posting them... just with care.

Comment: @Colas, please accept your answer as the correct answer as soon as you can, so that this question will have an accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Sheridan shouldn't that be a comment and not an answer? Also, that is an auto-generated comment, I did not put it.

Comment: @Parag, while I accept that this *is* a very poor quality answer and one that I myself would have flagged as 'not an answer', the question author *must* be given the chance to answer their own question.

Comment: @Colas, Parag *does* have a good point... your answer really *is* of very low quality. Even though this is your question, please read through the [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page from the StackOverflow Help Center to see how you can improve it.

Comment: I thought of deleting my post but then thought than somebody could be interested to see that a mistake in the repo has to be considered.